# Run .Net method once in a month

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, task-parallel-library, windows-task-scheduler

I have a windows service using .Net framework which needs to do some "work" once in a month. What is the best way to implement this?

I can think of the following options:

1) Do the "work" and sleep for 2592000 seconds (1 month equivalent).

2) Do the "work" and continue looping until desired date/time has reached? (sleeping for about 1 minute inside the loop).

3) Change it to a console application and let windows scheduler run the console application at specified date/time.

4) Any other way to force .net to start / continue the thread at specific date/time?

Comment: You can use [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) or [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

Comment: Interesting - I didn't know about these libraries. Thanks for the links. Btw, is there any built-in solution available in .Net framework?

Comment: 5) Add [Custom Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand?view=netframework-4.8) on which "work" is started. Write script that triggers said command. Have Windows scheduler run script at specified times.

Comment: I agree with Fildor - this is a job for the Windows Task Scheduler. There are several libraries for doing this via C# on GitHub, [for example this one](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler).

Comment: There's a fair chance of a reboot during the month (assuming you're applying security patches, etc) so you can't rely on an internal timer or keeping a thread alive.

Comment: Good point @RobinBennett

Comment: Considering that this "work" once a month is the sole purpose of that service, I'd like to change my vote to 3) (in accordance with my answer).

Comment: Hangfire is highly recommended. That cron job executer is perfect. Trust me that's best solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Task Scheduler in Windows is a good and common option.

The other option is to use a scheduler library like for example [FluentScheduler](https://github.com/fluentscheduler/FluentScheduler). This requires your app to be up an running during the whole month though so I would go with the task scheduler and let it simply run the code to be executed and then let the process finish.

Suspending a thread or burning CPU cycles for a month (!) is nonsense so forget about `1)` and `2)` and probably also about using `FluentScheduler` if your process isn't mean to be truly long-running.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I agree suspending a thread for a month is too long.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer) object, which performs a callback at a specified interval.
I have used this for a windows service previously, and in the service I have a timer property like so:

```
public partial class SomeService : ServiceBase
{
    private Timer scheduler = null;

    private Timer Scheduler
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.scheduler == null)
            {
                this.scheduler = new Timer(new TimerCallback(this.ProcessingFunction));
            }
            return this.scheduler;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // Set first .Change value to trigger initial execution.
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.Scheduler.Dispose();
    }

    private void ProcessingFunction(object e)
    {
        // Do stuff here
        // Calculate and set next execution time with .Change
    }
}
```

See also [Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/timers) Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Do you have an example of how I can fit this inside a windows service? I need to keep the main thread alive otherwise the service will stop automatically.

Comment: I've done super-pseudo-code. I'm not sure what you mean that the service will automatically stop... I don't think windows services stop through inactivity? Certainly I used the code similar to above to execute tasks daily and weekly and didn't have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming the Service is not only for this "once-a-month-work"** but provides an actual service beyond that, I would:

1. Add a Custom Command (See [Dokumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand?view=netframework-4.8) )
2. Write a Script or Short Program that does nothing else, but trigger that command.
3. Use Windows Task Scheduler to have that Script/Program be executed according to the desired schedule.

Pros:

- You can keep most of your existing code mostly unchanged.
- You have a "real" scheduler managed by windows

  - Reboots: check
  - Configurable Error handling: check
  - Leap years considered: check
  - Daylight Savings considered: check
  - ...

EDIT

If that "once-a-month-work" is the only purpose of that Service, then this is not a suitable Application Format. In this case, I'd make it a Console app and have the Windows Task Scheduler schedule and run it. You have all the "pros" and get rid of Service management.

Comment: The service is only used to for this once a month work. Should I go for the task scheduler option?

Comment: If it is really for this purpose, only: make it a Console app and use Windows Task Scheduler, yes.